# Include guards vs #pragma once

Tags: programming, library

Is there any particular reason why `#pragma once` doesn't seem to be used in Arduino code? Is this just because it's not a well-known feature, or is there some overriding reason to use `#ifndef XXX_H`/`#define XXX_H`/`#endif`?

Comment: Might be that part of the Arduino core source code is older than `#pragma once`. Which is by the way non-standard. It was introduced in GCC 3.4.

Comment: `#pragma once` is not a standard feature.

Comment: Non-standard but damn useful. Would be wise to consider adding support for it.

Comment: all `#pragma`s are non-standard by definition. However, I started using them in about 1986 in various C compilers and it seemed pretty ubiquitous even then. I guess I'm surprised that's not the case in the C++ world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#pragma once` operates on the absolute filename of a file. Include guards work on the content of the file.

If you have multiple copies of the same library (maybe one library has some parts of another included in it - it happens...) `#pragma once` would have no hope of working right.

Add to that the fact that the Arduino IDE copies some files around the place when building and `'#pragma once` is pretty much screwed.

Include guards work regardless. So sensible people use include guards and shun `#pragma once`.